# if T is aligned, std::vector<T> is aligned too?

Tags: c++, caching, c++11, vector, memory-alignment

I was browsing some of the new C++14 features and [aligned_storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) caught my attention, and after following a talk about concurrency, locality and data structure alignment, I was thinking about the fact that the chunk of memory allocated for an `std::vector` is guaranteed to be contiguos in memory, but this doesn't necessarily means that the vector itself is efficiently packed, or in better terms, the data that you care about is efficiently aligned, there could be extra stuff in terms of information about that data structure that are not necessarily useful for computation purposes and that can interfere with your data .

So I'm asking, if I have a `class T` and I know that `T` is aligned and packed as I like, `std::vector<T>` will be cache friendly and aligned in the pipeline too ?

My question covers C++11 and C++14 and it's only about data structures layouts, I'm not considering additional problems related to the organization of the cache lines like false sharing, or other problems related to how things get fetched, loaded and executed .

I know that this can sound silly, but it's just a doubt that I have.

Comment: The page you linked to says C++11.

Comment: @chris there is a part that says `since C++14` with the related differences.

Comment: You *are* guaranteed that the memory pointed to by `data()` consists of contiguously arranged elements of type `T`. Isn't that enough?

Comment: The only C++14 thing I see is the shortcut for `typename blah<blah>::type` (which you can make yourself in C++11 if you want).

Comment: @KerrekSB well, 1) there is no explicit guarantee about the fact that the chunk of memory is just for my data 2) to be cache friendly not only you need contiguos memory, you need aligned data 3) move semantics is also called pointer semantics, and pointers generate aliasing, and the problem with that is sometimes something decay into something else. I have my small doubts about the fact that this phrase alone can guarantee that I'll be ok in this situation.

Comment: @chris yes, but I take both anyway, so ... my point is about `std::vector`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I still don't have a firm answer, I don't think that this question is so obvious as it sounds.

Comment: I don't really understand your concerns. Elements of a vector are uniquely owned by a vector, suitably aligned, and contiguous. Maybe post some representative code which you're worried about?

Comment: @KerrekSB not worried of anything in particular, but a vector is guaranteed to be contiguos, not aligned, and as far as I know, `contiguos != aligned` they are just 2 different words. In concurrency I learned to redefine my definitions about programming a little bit and things are not so obvious, sometimes code with an `if` runs better then one without it, and sometimes both `array of structures` and `structures of array` are contiguos piece of memory but they lead to different kinds of performances . I don't know why but I don't think that this is that simple.

Comment: Vector elements are contiguous *and* each element is indeed suitably aligned for `T` (as understood by `alignof(T)`). What is missing?

Comment: @KerrekSB well, I guess that I'm not convinced, as simple as that, I don't know why, but probably I should try something, I was hoping for some definitive answer about pipelines and C++ data structures, not just the C++ standard, more like an explanation that starts from C++ containers and ends in the micro-architecture of the CPU.

Comment: Maybe [this demo](https://ideone.com/eJsfGX) helps?

Comment: @user2485710 Jumping in late here, but what do you mean by *pipelines*?

Comment: @Jeff cache pipeline, the cache, I have seen slightly different representations and wording about this, but basically I mean the cache

Comment: @KerrekSB nope, for the simple fact that this is implementation specific behaviour, I can show you some code that says that `double` is 64 bit but this doesn't mean that for the standard or for all the platforms out there `double = 64 bit`

Comment: @user2485710 Pipeline is almost certainly the wrong term for conveying your needs here. "Cache line" is probably what you're looking for. If you need, e.g., 64B alignment for x86 cache lines, you will need to make a custom allocator and/or use `std::aligned_storage`.

Comment: Support for over-aligned types is indeed implementation specific, but then again, so is "cache". If you can't get a type aligned to the size of a cache line, you can always add manual padding so that no two payloads end up on the same cache line.

Comment: @user2485710 You should probably rename this question to "Does std::vector<T> maintain member alignment?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ default allocators are required to align structs properly aligned for any so-called standard type, and **padding automatically added at the end of a struct (visible via `sizeof()`) generally facilitates this in contiguous allocations.**

```
struct C {
  uint8_t  a; // followed by 7B of invisible padding to naturally align b
  uint64_t b;
  uint32_t c;
  uint8_t  d; // followed by 3B padding for C (natural alignment of 8B due to b)
};
// sizeof(C) = 24B, alignof(C) = 8B

struct D {
  uint8_t  a; // followed by 3B padding for b
  uint32_t b;
  uint8_t  c; // followed by 3B padding for D (natural alignment of 4B due to b)
};
// sizeof(D) = 12B, alignof(D) = 4B

struct E {
  __m256 v; // SSE/AVX intrinsics handle natural alignment properly too
  char v2;
};
// sizeof(E) = 64B, alignof(E) = 32B
```

For most cases, this is adequate, but **if you are doing fancy casting tricks or need 64B cache line alignment, etc., you can use `alignas()`, provided you are using C++11 or newer**. This works partially by padding the end of the structure too:

```
struct alignas(64) F {
  double stuff[3];
};
// sizeof(F) = 64B, alignof(F) = 64B

void foo() {
  F f[4];
  // these addresses separated by (and even multiples of) 0x40 bytes:
  cout << &f[0] << " " << &f[1] << " " << &f[2] << endl;
}
```

Use `std::aligned_storage<T>` if you need a large block aligned against, e.g., 4 kiB page boundaries. But then you're on your own with placement `new` in general and lose the convenience of `std::vector<>` doing everything for you.

Comment: you are using a 64 byte alignment because you are assuming the use of `AVX` registers or for other reasons ? plus can you give an example for the custom allocator ?

Comment: @user2485710 a custom allocator is a fairly involved topic and beyond the scope of your question. I changed my answer a bit to give you a simpler drop-in solution via `alignas()`. You probably shouldn't worry about `std::aligned_storage<>` unless you need page boundary alignment as well.

Comment: thanks, what about the AVX/64 byte align ? Why you pick that number ?

Comment: SSE registers are 16B, AVX are 32B, and AVX-512 will be 64B, which matches the 64B cache line size found in all relevant x86_64 processors. 64 is the most you'll need for years for individual structs.

Comment: yes, I know that, but I was curious on why you were using 64B, since I'm planning to target SSE2/3 CPUs with my code I was making sure that we were on the same page. Maybe I was wrong about `AVX` I should have said `AVX2`, but that is what I was thinking about anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @user2485710 AVX/AVX2 use 32B registers, so `alignas(32)` would be sufficient for them. I've done a fair bit of cache-line alignment but not much SSE/AVX, so 64 was just the more "natural" value for me to throw in an example.

Comment: @user2485710 Also, if you're using the AVX intrinsic types (`__m256`) as struct members, all of this is taken care of for you automatically via natural alignment.